# Symfony2 Doctrine select dummy column with dumy value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to have:

```
select *, 0 as count from abc;
```

In doctrine query builder. I am using Symfony2

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$r = $qb->select('s, 0 as count')
        ->from('Wenweipo\SmileysBundle\Entity\Smileys', 's')
        ->innerJoin('s.group', 'g')
        ->where('g.id = :group_id')
        ->setParameter('group_id', $group_id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

But the above query doesn't work.

Comment: 1. You should use `getResult()` rather `execute()`; 2. Does it throw any exception?

Comment: Error: Class 'FROM' is not defined."

Comment: `count` is a reserved word. Use  ` or another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @meze commented i updated the field name and it worked fine.

```
$r = $qb->select('s,0 as aaaa')
                ->from('Wenweipo\SmileysBundle\Entity\Smileys', 's')
                ->innerJoin('s.group', 'g')
                ->where('g.id = :group_id')
                ->setParameter('group_id', $group_id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```